# deletion of repeated STRING words

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, repeater

I have an output of words, but they are repeated, I need to exclude repetitions, so that the output would be the same format (STRING) that I entered.

For example:

i use, sequelize database and map:

```
const myreqdb = await Model.findall();
myreqdb.map((v) => {
console.log(v.status.split('_')[0]) 
console.log(v.status) 
//ok
//ok
//ok_false
//ok_true
//no
//no_false
//no_true
//db_true
//ff_false
console.log(v.status.split('_')[0]) 
//ok
//ok
//ok
//ok
//no
//no
//no
//db
//ff
})
```

I need an exit like this:

```
ok
false
db
ff
```

this is a quick example, the titles are quite different and there are more of them.

Comment: `I need help fast` - that's really not what we do here.

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9229645/14054111y)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

you could use  by [fnxt/array/uniqueBy](https://fnxt-js.github.io/core/en/array/operator/uniqueBy/):

`npm i fnxt`

```
import { uniqueBy } from 'fnxt/array';
let words = ['a','b','a']
let uniqueWords = uniqueBy((item) => item)(words)
```

Comment: Hello, I don't want to use the library. Sorry

Comment: @user21059953 then lookup the source code